# How come the set of all binary strings is uncountable?

Tags: binary, uncountability, ordering

Sorry for bumping this very old problem which already has answers on multiple SE sites, but I just cannot understand any of the answers.

Let $\Sigma_{bool} = \{0, 1\}$.

Then, $(\Sigma_{bool})^*$ is the set of all binary strings, as far as I know. I've seen many posts claiming this set is uncountable. But how is that possible? If I sort the elements by length and then lexicographically, I get an ordering. Ordering of a set is, by definition, a bijection to a subset of natural numbers.

I would get:

| $\Sigma_{bool}$ | $\mathbb{N}$ |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 00 | 2 |
| 01 | 3 |
| 10 | 4 |
| 11 | 5 |
| 000 | 6 |
| 001 | 7 |
| ... | ... |

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560968/is-the-set-of-all-possible-binary-strings-countable) claims that it matters if the strings are of infinite length - why does it matter? I don't see it, can you please explain?

Comment: The set of finite binary strings is countable. The set of infinite binary strings is uncountable. That's just the way it is. Finite and infinite behave differently.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Which one of these is $(\Sigma_{bool})^*$ if defined as above?

Comment: $\Sigma^*$ is the set of finite words over $\Sigma$. In contrast, $\Sigma^\omega$ is the set of infinite words over $\Sigma$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus So, if I understand correctly, words of infinite length, such as $000...$ or $010101...$ do not belong to $(\Sigma_{bool})^*$.

Comment: Right, $\Sigma^*$ consists only of finite words.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Isn't there a concept of [countably infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)? Then why you said that the set of infinite binary strings is uncountable? Did you mean infinitely "length" binary strings?

Comment: The set of all infinite binary strings is uncountable. That's just the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok more theoretic proof here

#### If you are only looking at finite strings

by definition
$$\Sigma_{bool}^* = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \Sigma_{bool}^i$$

(where $\Sigma_{bool}^i$ is the set of strings of length $i$)

$\Sigma_{bool}^i$ is finite, therefore countable. So this is a countable union of countable sets, [and therefore countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable).

#### If you are looking at infinite strings

Your set is actually the set of sequences on $\Sigma_{bool}$ or equivalently, the set of mappings from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\Sigma_{bool}$.

$$\Sigma_{bool}^{\mathbb{N}}$$

It is bijective to the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$

This is not countbale because of [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the set of all the *infinite binary strings* (i.e. $\Sigma^{\omega}$), then whatever enumeration $E = (s_1, s_2, s_3, ... )$ you build for them you can build a string $s'$ that is not in $E$ using a simple diagonalization argument:

$s'[i] = 1 - s_i[i]$,  $i \geq 1$

where $s_i[i]$ is the $i$-th digit of $s_i$.

$s'$ (which has infinite length) is different from any (infinite) string in $E$.

If you only consider the set of all *finite binary strings*, the enumeration you wrote in the question is enough to prove that it is countable.